# How to put dictionary output of a function into a dataframe when function runs n times?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

So I've written this function for a particular game simulation. I have removed the irrelevant part from my code here.

```py
def play(games=1):
    for j in range (1,games+1):
        from itertools import chain
        Player1,Player2=deal()
        #print(Player1,Player2)
        l1=[]
        l2=[]
        l3=[]
        l4=[]
        count = 0
        for i in range(0,26,2):
            .
            .
            .
        Stats={'Initial total of Player 1 ':sum(Player1),
               'Initial total of Player 2 ':sum(Player2),
               'Number of Ties ':count,
               'Maximum round total won ':max(l4),
               'Final total of Player 1 ':sum(l1),
               'Final total of Player 2 ':sum(l2)}
        print (Stats)
```

So, `play()` would give `{'Initial total of Player 1 ': 185, 'Initial total of Player 2 ': 179, 'Number of Ties ': 0, 'Maximum round total won ': 40, 'Final total of Player 1 ': 229, 'Final total of Player 2 ': 135}` as the output.

Similarly `play(2)` would give `{'Initial total of Player 1 ': 164, 'Initial total of Player 2 ': 200, 'Number of Ties ': 0, 'Maximum round total won ': 34, 'Final total of Player 1 ': 76, 'Final total of Player 2 ': 288}`
`{'Initial total of Player 1 ': 179, 'Initial total of Player 2 ': 185, 'Number of Ties ': 1, 'Maximum round total won ': 43, 'Final total of Player 1 ': 155, 'Final total of Player 2 ': 209}`. Here '2' as the argument means the number of game simulations.

Now I need how to insert each dictionary out into pandas dataframe wherein the indexes of the dictionary would be the column and the values would be the rows. So for example '5' game simulations would mean a dataframe with 5 data rows, one for each time a dictionary was generated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi and welcome to StackOverflow!

The problem is that we are running a loop and not saving the values. We merely print them. Try something along these lines:

```
def play(games=1):
    rounds = []
    for j in range (1, games + 1):
        from itertools import chain
        Player1, Player2 = deal()
        #print(Player1,Player2)
        l1 = []
        l2 = []
        l3 = []
        l4 = []
        count = 0
        for i in range(0,26,2):
            .
            .
            .
        stats = {'Initial total of Player 1 ':sum(Player1),
               'Initial total of Player 2 ':sum(Player2),
               'Number of Ties ':count,
               'Maximum round total won ':max(l4),
               'Final total of Player 1 ':sum(l1),
               'Final total of Player 2 ':sum(l2)}
        print(stats)
        rounds.append(stats)
    return rounds
```

Now when you run this function, it will return a list of dictionaries. Each dictionary contains the values of one data row.

```
data_rows = play()
```

To turn this into a data frame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(data_rows)
```

Comment: Hey Thanks for the help! But I had a follow up doubt. This particular method prints the dictionary first and then stores it in a dataframe. So say I simulate this game a 100 times to put the values into the dataframe, it would also give 100 dictionaries as outputs. Any way to avoid this and insert directly into the dataframe?

Comment: @VedantSrivastava of course! The printing is optional and merely aids the debugging. You should remove the line `print(stats)` at some point.